# How to connect to Heroku postgres database from a local connection in php

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku, local

I'm trying to access to my Heroku Postgres database from a php code that runs locally.

```
pg_connect("host=myhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=me password=*** sslmode=require options='--client_encoding=UTF8'")
```

works well when the code runs on Heroku, but not locally. (the value are those given by Heroku)

I get this error :

> Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: sslmode value "require"
>   invalid when SSL support is not compiled in

If I delete sslmode, I get this error :

> Network is unreachable Is the server running on host "myhost" and
>   accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Does someone has a clue ? It would help a lot !

Comment: When you say locally, are you changing host= to a local host?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku Postgres requires sslmode for external connections. You likely need to compile PHP with the `--with-openssl[=dir]` compile flag. See here for more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php

Can you verify your installation of PHP has openssl compiled in with it? The only way I know to check this is with a `phpinfo()` page and look for the `--with-openssl` flag.